# Automating Training for Custom Speech Model

Tags: speech-recognition, chatbot, speech, azure-bot-service, azure-speech

I am working on a requirement where I have created a custom speech model for Azure Chatbot. I have uploaded some audio files in https://speech.microsoft.com , created a model and then deployed it  manually for getting model id and speech recognition endpoint id. I have done all these steps manually in speech studio, but I want to know if there is any way to automate this process for updating the files. ie. if the audio files would be in some azure blob storage, is there any way if these would be uploaded to azure speech studio automatically through some azure function, so that model is created and deployed.

I have earlier automated Luis model similarly by uploading file to azure blob and then created an azure function to upload to Luis for updating the utterances. So, can anyone guide me if there is any way in Custom Speech model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look at the swagger API reference here: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/speech-to-text-api-v3-0/operations/CreateModel
You can create data sets/models/endpoints using the above REST API. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! it worked and I was able to trigger REST calls

Comment: Hi again, I have tried triggering multiple REST API's ( create dataset, create model and create endpoint) serially and I have just realized that unless I click "connect" in my speech studio, the dataset or model created from REST calls is not updating in Speech Studio. Below is the message I get in my Speech Studio and every time I need to click Connect. `We have found unconnected datasets in the same language with your subscription. You may have created them from the old portal or through the APIs. Do you want to connect these entities to this project so you can manage them?`

Comment: I want to know if adding new files, creating new models and deploying models can be automated with out manually clicking Connect as below, because unless I click Connect the new files are not reflecting in the portal.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with "Connect" coming in Custom Speech studio for every request API can be resolved by appending project details as below in the request body.

```
"project": {
    "self": "https://eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/YOUR PROJECT URL"
}
```